# How to set chosen image to input type='file' in webview

Tags: android, webview

I trying to open file or image with on webview on android 4.4.1 & 4.4.2.Since the callback methods are removed for these 2 versions, I added an event to the `button type="file"` and showed a filechoser. My problem is after choosing the file, I'm not able to atatch it to the `button type="file"`. When I tried by changing the `button type="text"`, it shows the file path name. But I want to use button `type="file"`.

My `onActivityResult()` code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
    if (kitkat()) {
        String realPathFromURI = "";
        String fullPathUri = null;
        if (intentData != null) {
            Uri uri = intentData.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(uri.toString());
                realPathFromURI = Utility.getRealPathFromURI(this, uri1);
                if (null != realPathFromURI) {
                    File file = new File(Utility.getRealPathFromURI(this, uri1));
                    boolean isMaxSize = Utility.isMaxFileSize(file.length());
                    if (isMaxSize) {
                        if (this != null)
                            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "File Size too large",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    fullPathUri = file.toString();
                } else {
                    if (this != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Invalid File Format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            realPathFromURI = "";

            fullPathUri = mCameraPhotoPath;
        }
        String msgToSend = realPathFromURI;
        browser.loadUrl("javascript:KitKatWebviewChooseImgResult(\"" + msgToSend + "\")");
    } else {
        // code for all versions except of Lollipop
    }
}

private boolean kitkat() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("4.4.1") || android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("4.4.2")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and HTML code:

```
<input name="file" id="files" style="width:195px;font-size:12px;" type="file" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Please select a file"  onclick="showFileChoser()">
```

script:

```
function showFileChoser() {
    choser.choseImage();
}

function KitKatWebviewChooseImgResult(msg) {
    document.getElementById("files").value = msg;
}
```

When I changed the `input type="text"`, it takes the input and path is shown in the webview. But the same code is not working when `input type="text` is set".

After choosing the file, How to attach it to `button type="file"`.
Thanks in Advance.